# The Birthday Paradox, revisited

Tags: mathematics, probability

My niece, a medical consultant, sees a number of patients every day, and the first thing she asks is for their birthday. Recently, in a certain week, patients 16 and 17 shared the same birthday (though not same year).

How surprised should she be?

More precisely, if she sees *n* patients in a week, what are the chances that two, one after another, share the same birthday?

Comment: Can you clarify the question for this: are you asking for exact 2 or at least 2?

Comment: Unless I am missing something, this isn't really a puzzle but a straightforward math question.

Answer (score 8):

The chance that

> patients 16 and 17 had the same birthday

is

> 1/365.25-ish, of course. It's the same as the probability that any two given people share the same birthday.

But you probably meant the chance that

> *any* two consecutive patients had the same birthday. That's *not* the birthday paradox, because you don't build up a "pool" of birthdays over time. The chance that patient `i`, `1 < i <= n`, has the same birthday as the patient before them is given above. Each patient is an independent trial: A patient sharing, or not sharing, a birthday with the patient before them, doesn't affect the chances of them sharing a birthday with the patient after them. (This isn't precisely true, because of the effect of leap years, but I'm ignoring that quite small effect, which would in any case be swamped by the effect of seasonal variation in birth rate.)

> So, overall, it's `1 - (1-(1/365.25))^(n-1)`, the standard formula for at least one success in `n-1` independent trials. (`n-1` because of course the first patient can't match the one before them.)

Overall,

> mildly surprised, but not "won the lottery" surprised.

Comment: But this is essentially an infinite stream, week after week.  Assuming one patient every 30 minutes in a 40-hour work week is about a 20% chance of it happening in any given week.  But put 4 weeks back to back and it's a 58% chance that it will happen sometime in a month.   A 99.99% chance it will occur sometime during the year.   I am not surprised at all!

Comment: @DanielWiddis things don’t have to have never happened before in order to be mildly surprising. They test the fire alarm once a month at my office and it’s mildly surprising.

Comment: no-one allve today was born on a skipped leap year, (last was 1900) so 1/365.25 would be accurate except that birthdays are not uniformly distributed

Comment: @Jasen the issue isn’t skipped leap years, but non-uniform binning. Someone who failed to match the previous patient has a slightly higher posterior probability of having been born on a leap day, and thus a slightly lower probability of matching the following patient.

Answer (score 1):

Sneftel's answer is on the button except that the question specifically states that she sees 'a number' of patients every day, and sees **n patients in a week**. On the assumption that she sees the same number (n/7) of patients each day, then the chance that she *doesn't* see two consecutively same birthday patients in a single day is

> p=(364.25/365.25)^(n/7-1),

and the chance she doesn't see two consecutive same birthday patients in a week is p^7. So the chance she does see two consecutive birthday patients in a week is

> q=1.0 - (364.25/365.25)^(n-7).

We know that 'some number' is at least 17, i.e. n >= 119, so the probability she will see such a thing in a typical week is at least

> 0.02704.

So in a year (seeing the same number of patients every day) and taking only two weeks off for holidays, there would be at least a

> 75%

chance that such an event would happen some time during the year. So all in all a pretty mundane experience.

Comment: Why is she working 7 days a week?

Comment: @PM2Ring cause she's in healthcare. Everybody in healthcare works 8 days per week 40 hours per day. :D

Comment: Our nurses in the US work three 12 hour shifts per week. 36 hours total. 4 days off per week!